# UDP responding datagram timeout

Tags: android, sockets

Background:

I'm trying to implement hole punching (https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix05/tech/general/full_papers/ford/ford.pdf).  I have no problem punching a hole when on the same private network (e.g. both devices are on my router).  However, when trying to punch through across NATs (i.e., using the public ip/port), it works only after many repeated  punch attempts.  An observation I noticed, is that on the time it did successfully punch through the firewall, the timing was such that both devices attempted to punch through within 500ms of each other.  I'm thinking this is not a concidence and the punches need to be coordinated such that they are synchronized or at least extremely close, maybe < 500ms

Question: When a device sends a datagram (UDP), how long can the responding device take to respond to it?  In other words, by virtue of sending a packet from your device, binded to a specific port, the firewall will allow incoming traffic addressed to the binded port.

Comment: The persistence of a UDP hole or the response time required to create it surely depends on individual routers and their settings?

Comment: Since udp is conectionless, about how long will this hole stay open for?  Milliseconds, seconds, etc?  Every udp packet that is sent through a router, the router anticipates a reply.  How long later can that reply be before the router rejects it; thinking that the incoming packet is not part of the original "session"? I know there is probably no direct answer since every router along the way will be configured differently but I'm just looking for a rough order of magnitude?